# Bootstrap - changing the width of a form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I have the following code in an ember application for a .hbs template file (basically it's just a chat box for a user to enter text, with "Back" and "Send" buttons either side):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="chat-form text-left">
      <button class="btn btn-default" {{action "back"}}>Back</button>
      <form class="form-inline" {{action "handleMessage" on="submit"}}>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only">Chat Message</label>
            {{input value=chatMessage class="form-control"}}
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Currently the text box is too narrow and I want to make it a few times wider, I'm aware of columns and spans in bootstrap but as a complete beginner I'm not sure how to do it properly in this case.

Comment: try this way https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to utilize bootstrap grid system. I'm providing one example here.

**Example Snippet**

```css
#inpt {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="chat-form text-left col-xs-12">
<div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-10">
          <form class="form-inline">
             <div class="form-group col-xs-9">
                <label class="sr-only">Chat Message</label>

                <input id="inpt" value=chatMessage class="form-control">

             </div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</div>
          </form>
</div>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```